# Solving Exponential equation in MATLAB parametrically

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

i want to solve this equation...

```
 | 1     1     1 | |b0| |exp(t)  |
 | 0     1     2 | |b1|=|exp(t)  |
 | 1     1     1 | |b2| |exp(2*t)|
```

i like the answer be like this:

for example:

b0=2*exp(t)+exp(2*t)
b1=exp(t)+1
b2=exp(

Comment: You can't solve that linear system, it's dependent (many solutions).

Comment: Actually, there are many solutions when `t=0` and no solutions otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That matrix is singular, so there's no unique solution (depending on `t`, there may be zero or infinitely many solutions).  I will replace it with an invertible matrix to demonstrate the method:

```
>> A = [1,1,1;0,1,2;1,1,0]

A =

     1     1     1
     0     1     2
     1     1     0
```

After that, solving is a straightforward use of the symbolic capability:

```
>> t = sym('t');
>> rhs = [exp(t);exp(t);exp(2*t)]

rhs =

   exp(t)
   exp(t)
 exp(2*t)
>> b = A\rhs

b =

   exp(t) - exp(2*t)
 2*exp(2*t) - exp(t)
   exp(t) - exp(2*t)
```

Comment: Hi mr. Ben Voigt...thank you for your help...but i hace matrix like this    |0  -2  1 |     
%   a=  |-1 -2  2 | 
%       |0  -2  1 |   that i wanted to solve it in hamilton style(e^at) and the ansert must be like this form(parametric) 
              |2e^t-e^2t  0     2e^t-2e^2t|
              | 0         e^t    0        |
              |e^2t        0    2e^2t-e^t | but thank you for replying anyway..be goodluck.